# Posted bounty, answered my question myself, where do the points go?

Tags: support, bounty

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302732/ruby-on-rails-why-is-materialize-updatetextfields-not-a-function) has no other answers and has not had an answer for the past >2 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points go nowhere

from [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on MSE:

> **Can I award a bounty to my own answer?**
>
> No. This used to be possible, [but it has been disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97802). The user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as +0, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.